# How can I redirect my domain to a different page or directory?

Tags: web-hosting

Please suggest  a method other than use of .htaccess..

Answer (score 7):

It really is homework-due-day today.

Theres httpd.conf (apache) 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/configuring.html

Or, forcing an "Error 301 - redirect".

Or, you could put a meta-refresh in your webpage redirecting to the new webpage. 
e.g.
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.the-domain-you-want-to-redirect-to.com">

Or you could use javascript to force the redirect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
</script>
```

Then there are things like Reverse Proxy that could do what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the technology and/or your access to the web server there are various options.  In addition to the above you could use a server side code redirect e.g. in ASP.Net

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.google.co.uk")
```

I'm sure there are PHP and various other code alternatives to perform the same action.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a client side redirect using an index.html and a META Refresh tag.

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.mysite.com/MyDir/MyPage.html" />
        </head>
    </html>
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Answer (score 0):

Implementation-agnostic:

The following status codes can be used in a web server response:

- [301 Moved Permanently](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2)
- [302 Found](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3)

If you don't have access to a decent web server, try the Javascript
or Meta-Tag methods above.

Bonus: another implementation-specific advice, using [Hunchentoot](http://weitz.de/hunchentoot):

```
(redirect "http://otherhost/otherpath")
```